# How to make video fullscreen on mobile

Tags: html, css, html5-video, html5-fullscreen

I am developing a website for a client, which contains a few videos, you can see it at this adress : https://clad.web.epfprojets-sceaux.com/index.php

The problem is about the 100% width video, not the 3 first.

To make videos go fullscreen on laptop, I use :

```
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
            elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
```

It appears it doesn't work when I browse the site from my iPhone 8 on google chrome.

Can someone help me find how to fix this problem please ?

Comment: I tried with my IphoneSE and the width is 100% in chrome. Is the height your issue?

Comment: The problem is when I try to make the video full screen, It won't work on mobile